# Evaluate a function in terms of a numpy array

Tags: python, function, numpy

I'm not really sure if this is how to plot a function (it gives me the error: "TypeError: 'float' object is not callable" for the variable N).
I'm trying to plot F, a composition of the function N that depends on T.

```
import numpy as np 

T = np.arange(5000, 25000, 1000)
N = ((3.4*(10**-3))(T**1.5)(e**((1.6*(10**5))/T)))
F = (N/(1+N))
```

Comment: `e` is not defined. Once you do that you are essentially calling a float `(0.1)(0.2)(0.3)`. Multiplication in python is defined via the operator `*`. Hence what you probably want to do is `(0.1)*(0.2)*(0.3)` instead.

Comment: Explain what `N` ia supposed to be doing.  The error comes from the three `(...)(...)(...)` expressions.  Python interprets that as calling a function(s).